# Wildcard Substitution in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have an Ubuntu 10.04 OS, and if I do this on the terminal (it works):

```
$ ssh new_machine "find /tmp/test_*.csv -mtime +14 -exec rm '{}' \;"
```

But if I place it in a shell script, it does not work. I suspect it is related to the "*" wildcard. Any thoughts on doing this?

Answer (score 3):

You don't want globbing at all, you want find to be doing that.  I think this might work:

`$ ssh new_machine "find /tmp -name 'test_*.csv' -mtime +14 -exec rm '{}' \;"`

Comment: I just checked it and there are no files on the local machine. I am sending the command via ssh to the new_machine...

Comment: I got it backwards, you don't want to glob at all.  Take a look at the edited answer.

Comment: Interesting. That works. Can you explain why my original command was not working? What was happening to my wildcard?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I suspect that absolutely nothing was happening to it.  The find command doesn't run in a shell when you invoke it via ssh.  So there's nothing to expand the wildcard except find itself, and it may not do that on that argument.  Try ssh new_machine "echo /tmp/test_*.csv" and see if you get what you expect.

Comment: @Carmen: When you run the command without the quotes, the shell expands the wildcard in `/tmp/test_*.csv`. Normally the expansion is the list of matching file names, but if there happens to be no matching file, then the expansion is the single word `/tmp/test_*.csv`, as if there had been quotes, so only then does `find` see the argument you meant.

Comment: @Andrew: It *does* run in a shell, always.